# gcc Link Order issue

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

I am currently having problems compiling with the following line:

```
gcc test.c -I/usr/include -L/lib -lipc -lpcd -lrt -o /home/examples/bin/test
```

I was suggested to group them using start-group and end-group.

I am not able to get the proper syntax.

I think i need this part, but what do the whole line look like?

> `-Wl,--start-group -lipc -lpcd -lrt -Wl,--end-group`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have to passit all down to the linker as one big argument -Wl,--start-group,-lipc,-lpcd,-lrt,--end-group

Comment: gcc test.c -I/usr/include -L/lib -Wl,--start-group -lipc -lpcd -lrt -Wl,--end-group -o /home/examples/bin/test
Like this? it doesn't work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is an extremely imprecise problem description. You might get better advice if you provided a better explanation of what happens. (For example, if there is an error message, quote it verbatim. Or describe what happens: "The monitor shattered when I executed that command.")

Comment: I get the same error message as I originally had. It is an undefined reference to functions that I made sure were defined.

Comment: how is X defined? is it a C or C++ function?

Answer (score 0):

Which problem are you having ?

Anyway, try putting the linker arguments at the end:

```
gcc test.c -o /home/examples/bin/test -I/usr/include -L/lib -lipc -lpcd -lrt
```

Comment: I get an undefined reference as follows:
/lib/libpcd.so: undefined reference to 'X'